# Stretch a container inside a scrolled parent to match its children when they extend beyond the bounds of the parent

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/5hjw30x0/13/

Is there a clean html/css-only method to stretch a container inside a scrolled parent to match its children when they extend beyond the parent's size? If not, what's the fastest way to achieve this in Javascript?

Note how the border of the container stops at the bottom edge of the parent, while the children continue on past that edge. I want the children to define the height of the container, while still retaining the scroll region of the parent.

Thanks for the help!

[image: Edge in question]

```css
body {
  background-color: #a8a8a8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  position: absolute;
}

.header {
  background-color: #666666;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

.header2 {
  background-color: #ededed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  z-index: 9;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 -3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.columns, .columns_header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.columns_header {
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 30px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 1;
}

.column_title {
  padding: 3px 0 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
}

.column_title:last-child {
  border-right: 27px solid black;
}

.column_title:first-child {
  border-left: 10px solid black;
}

.columns {
  background-color: #ededed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.column {
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #666666;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column:last-child {
  border-right: 10px solid #666666;
}

.column:first-child {
  border-left: 10px solid #666666;
}

.activity {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

```html
<body class="">

  <div class="header">

  </div>


  <div class="header2">

  </div>

  <div class="columns_header">

    <div class="column_title">
    </div>

    <div class="column_title">
    </div>

    <div class="column_title">
    </div>

    <div class="column_title">
    </div>

    <div class="column_title">
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="columns">

    <div class="column">

      <div class="activity">
      </div>

      <div class="activity">
      </div>

      <div class="activity">
      </div>

      <div class="activity">
      </div>

      <div class="activity">
      </div>

      <div class="activity">
      </div>

      <div class="activity">
      </div>

      <div class="activity">
      </div>

      <div class="activity">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="column">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: remove `height: 100%` from body. that's what is causing your column heights to be limited.

Comment: `body {position:absolute}` is absolutely pointless. You're removing everything from document flow and place it in an absolute flow (which becomes the document flow, because the document flow is empty). Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/epjdkLhy/) what you need?

Comment: I can think of a couple (albeit hacky and borderline irresponsible) ways to make a border-looking-element extend beyond a parent. Do you care about ever seeing content above or below that parent container? Or maintaining any gutter/white-space between the topmost or bottommost edges of the borders?

Comment: Sadly, yes. In my real page, I have headers and footers above/below. 
http://thepos.se/mkJQO.png

Comment: Edited the question to more accurately reflect the problem. Removing either position: absolute or height: 100% currently breaks the page layout.